# How can i create reusable backing structure?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I'm using JSF 2.2 and trying to make some reusable components. 
For example one of them should be a person searching dialog form. e.g:

**Subview:**

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:inputText value="#{subviewBean.name}"  >
    <h:inputText value="#{subviewBean.surname}"  >
<h:commandLink title="OK" value="OK" action="subvieewBean.okClick/>
</ui:composition>
```

I'm trying to include this subview to number of views, e.g.:

**View**

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" />
      <h:outputText id="outputId" value="#{viewBean.subviewBean.name} #{viewBean.subviewBean.surname}" />
</ui.composition>
```

With corresponging beans

```
@ManagedBean
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class SubviewBean{

    String name; //+ getter, setter
    String surname; //+ getter, setter

    ViewBean viewBean;

    public void okClick(){ 
        viewBean.okinsubviewClicked();
    }
}

@ManagedBean
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class ViewBean{

    SubviewBean subviewBean;
    okinsubviewClicked() {
        rerender(outputId)
}
```

That's not my real code but more like JSF-styled pseudocode purposed to illustrate my intentions.

On pressing "ok" button data from searchBean should be somehow transferred to viewBean or view2Bean which may have some simillarities with viewBean, and may not. Anyway, i want subview to transfer name and surname to any bean i want to, or work standalone. More than that, master bean must rerender some components after subview do the work. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `<f:param>`-tag

```
<h:commandButton action="#{subviewBean.someAction}">
    <f:param name="name" value="#{subviewBean.name}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

And in `ViewBean`

```
@ManagedProperty("#{param.name}")
private String name;
```